# Proper way to modify a response in Flask with eg process_response

Tags: python, flask

Given a simple [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) application, I'm just curious about whether there is a proper way to modify a Response in the hooks such as `process_response`?

e.g. Given:

```
from flask import Flask, Response

class MyFlask(Flask):
    def process_response(self, response):
        # edit response data, eg. add "... MORE!", but
        # keep eg mimetype, status_code
        response.data += "... This is added" # but should I modify `data`?
        return response
        # or should I:
        #     return Response(response.data + "... this is also added",
        #                     mimetype=response.mimetype, etc)

app = MyFlask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "abddef"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Is it proper to just create a new response each time, or is it canonical to just edit in-place the response parameter and return that modified response?

This may be purely stylistic, but I'm curious – and I haven't noticed anything in my reading that would indicate the preferred way to do this (even though it's probably quite common).

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Flask.process_response docs:

*Can be overridden in order to modify the response object before it's sent to the WSGI server.*

The response object is created on flask dispacher mechanism (Flask.full_dispatch_request). So if you want to create response objects under your own way, override Flask.make_reponse. Use Flask.process_response only when the desired modifications can be made using the created response object parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can use `Flask.process_response` to intercept and modify the response this way:

```
from flask import Flask
import json
import ast

appVersion = 'v1.0.0'

class LocalFlask(Flask):
    def process_response(self, response):
        #Every response will be processed here first
        response.headers['App-Version'] = appVersion
        success = True if response.status_code in [ 200, 201, 204 ] else False
        message = 'Ok' if success else 'Error'
        dict_str = response.data.decode("UTF-8")
        dataDict = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
    
        standard_response_data = {
            'success': success,
            'message': message,
            'result': dataDict
        }
        response.data = json.dumps(standard_response_data)

        super(LocalFlask, self).process_response(response)
        return response
```